# setting the width of my footer to 100% shows a scrollbar

Tags: css

Although I set the width of my footer to 100%, there it extends to more than 100% having a scroll bar in terms of width. Any ideas why? I know the problem is the width because when I remove the 100%, it does not show the scroll bar. The page is broken down to body>wrapper>footer
Here is my code:

```
 #footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white !important;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

And there is the body css:

```
body {
  font: normal 12pt Georgia, serif;
  color: #111;
  background: #990000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  min-height: 100%;

  margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

And the wrapper css:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have padding set in your footer's css. That adds up to the width and makes it bigger than 100%. That's why you are seeing a scrollbar.

Replace the padding with these following lines.

```
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
```

Also by setting footer div's min width to 1000px, you will get the scrollbar in browser screens narrower than 1000px.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Hadn't realized I am setting paddint top differently. But isn't padding: 20px equivalent to padding-top: 20px?

Comment: @bigollo, when you set padding using "padding" only you're basically setting it in all 4 sides: top, bottom, right and left.. Unless you specify where you want the padding, this is the case in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is due to how the default [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box_model) works in html pages: after the width is set to 100% for content, the borders, margins and paddings are added, increasing the final width beyond 100%.

**For modern browsers: hail box-sizing!**

1. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NS2bh/) with your original code.
2. See [this newer version](http://jsfiddle.net/NS2bh/2/) with [**box sizing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) set to `border-box` (only works in newer browsers). This version doesn't show a horizontal scrollbar (I made the min-width a lot smaller, or it would throw off the example in jsfiddle).

**For older browsers**

If you want to fix this for older browsers you'll have to do something about the padding in your CSS. Remove it from the footer, and place a "footer-content" div inside with margins equal to your old paddings. E.g.:

```
#footer { 
    /* padding: 20px; removed! */
}
#footer-content { 
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks the jsfiddle is a very useful tool!

Answer (score 1):

Many browsers have a default margin around the BODY element, which adds to the width.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the padding. See the illustration of your problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jyVKZ/).

**When you use padding, the size gets added to the total height and width respectively.**

Removing the padding will fix your problem. [<sup>Demo</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/jyVKZ/1/)

```
 #footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white !important;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Another good solution is to make the browser treat your element differently. by using `box-sizing` property.

```
 #footer {
  /* Add box-sizing */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white !important;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jyVKZ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add 0 padding, 0 border and 0 margin to all elements at start.

```
* {
padding: 0;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```